# Meaning of sentence

Tags: meaning

I have some trouble understanding this sentence:

> AとかけましてBと解きます。その心はC。

Comment: This doesn't really appear to be a question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the format of a traditional Japanese joke in the form of a riddle (謎かけ). The wording is kind of fixed and outdated, so you may find it a bit difficult to understand from today's language.

> AとかけましてBと解きます。その心はC。
>   Literally: *(I) pose (you) A, and (you) answer B. The clue is... C.*
>   Meaning: *What do A and B have in common? It's C.*

What goes in *C* is the punch line and often is a pun on *A* and *B*. Sometimes the entire joke is given in monologue, sometimes it's played in Q&A style (the original way): "What is like *A*?" → "*B* is." → "Why?" → "Because *C*."

An example from [Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9E%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91):

> 「ミニスカート」とかけて、「結婚式のスピーチ」と解く。その心は「短いほど喜ばれる」
>   *Why is a "mini-skirt" like a "wedding speech"? Because "the shorter (they are), the more are pleased (with them)".*